# Does Non Negativity Constrains increases the estimation error

Tags: algorithms, unsupervised-learning

I have been working with Tensor and matrix Non negative constrained algorithms. I have never seen a non negative constrained algorithm (ex. Non Negative Tucker Decomposition **NTD**) with error that is comparable to the non constrained algorithm (ex.High Order SVD **HOSVD**). Publications normally don't compare estimation error of unconstrained algorithms with constrained algorithms instead the comparison is always between different algorithms of same type.

By Testing, I found that the result of constrained algorithms with noise is around $10^{-7}$ compared to unconstrained ones is around $10^{-15}$.

Any reference that I can start from or any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about train error or test error?
Non negativity constrains make your search space of possible solutions much smaller. This means that the train error would be always higher or equal when you add non-negativity constraint. 
But higher train error can mean that you are overfitting. If the assumption of non-negativity make sense for the solution of your problem, then it is likely that this assumption would decrease the test error as you are limiting your function space and decrease the chance of overfitting.

Comment: It is a test error as I am estimating blind sources by finding the minimum of objective function. The error is the $||X-X_{est} ||^2_F$. Some times in publications it is advised that constraint increase the performance for the same reason (searching in small areas), some times it increase the uniqueness and other times it increases the estimation error as the blind sources to be estimated generates positive data compared to SVD that provide negative factors estimation to this blind sources.

Comment: The non-negativity assumption only make sense for applications that your data has non-negative components. Then you decompose the prediction and put non-negativity assumption on that component. It is likely to increase the test-error with this constraint elsewhere.