# How does non-negative constrained optimization work?

Tags: logistic-regression, optimization

I am dealing with a machine learning problem in which a logistic regression model is trained with under-bound constrained optimization for model interpretability purposes.

In a simple 2-dimensional unconstrained case, let us assume that the loss function looks like below,

[image]

Now, if we constrain this optimization to be an under-bound constrained optimization i.e., the weights can only be zero or positive, would this be equivalent to slicing the loss function at `y=0` such that instead of a single global minimum, would we end up with a truncated structure like below,
[image]

If we try to find the minimum of this constrained loss function, can we expect to see different values for `x` (from -2 to +2) since all those values are resulting in a minimum value for the loss function?

If this is true, how would this affect the performance of this model with different sets of weights? Would different weights of `x` have no impact on the performance of the model?

I read in one of [SO threads](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/23473/67278) that non-negative constrained optimization makes the search space smaller. Can anyone help me understand this better?

Comment: No, I think it would be like truncating x not y.

Comment: My bad with creating the accurate diagram. I was intending to create a 3D diagram with both x and y as features. Given my case, do you think my question about multiple possible solution across the space where the loss function gets truncated is possible?

Comment: The global optimum might be outside your constrained range and in this case due to convexity you will find that your constrained solution will be on the boundary. I think it is unlikely there will be multiple solutions.

Comment: If it is on the boundary, it does mean that for all possible values of `y` feature on this boundary, we will get the same minimum value for our optimization function. So, doesn't it cause the optimization problem to have multiple solutions?